# The multiplication formula for the Hurwitz zeta function

Tags: analysis, special-functions, zeta-functions

In a textbook I'm reading, the author states without proof that $$ \zeta(s,mz) = \frac{1}{m^{s}} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \zeta \left(s,z+\frac{k}{m} \right), \tag{1}$$ where $\zeta(s,z) $ is the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function)

Supposedly, this isn't hard to prove. But is it possible to prove $(1)$ using simply the series definition of the Hurwitz zeta function, that is,   $ \displaystyle\zeta(s,z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z+n)^{s}}$?

It might be interesting to note that the [polygamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function#Special_cases_and_generalizations) (excluding the digamma function) can be expressed in terms of the Hurwitz zeta function.

So from $(1)$ we can derive the multiplication formula $$\psi_{n}(mz) = \frac{1}{m^{n+1}} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\psi_{n} \left(z+ \frac{k}{m} \right) , \quad n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}.$$

Comment: it is obvious ${}{}$

Comment: Given any totally multiplicative series, whose Fourier transform exists, one can construct a function obeying the multiplication theorem.The Wikipedia article [multiplication theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem) explains why and how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We start with $\displaystyle \zeta(s,z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z+n)^{s}}$.

First, substitute in $mz$ for $z$:

$$\begin{align}
\zeta(s,mz) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(mz+n)^{s}} \\
&= \frac{1}{m^s}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z+\frac{n}{m})^{s}}.
\end{align}$$

Now write $n = n'm + n''$, where now $n'$ will range from $0$ to $\infty $ and $n''$ will range from $0$ to $m-1$. Putting this above gives
$$\begin{align}
&= \frac{1}{m^s}\sum_{\substack{n'\geq 0 \\ n'' \bmod m}} \frac{1}{(z+\frac{n''}{m} + n')^{s}} \\
&= \frac{1}{m^s} \sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} \sum_{n' \geq 0} \frac{1}{(z + \frac km + n')^s} \\
&= \frac{1}{m^s}\sum_{k =0}^{m-1}\zeta\left(s,z+\frac{k}{m}\right),
\end{align}$$

as we wanted to show.

Comment: So you just used the division algorithm?

Comment: @RandomVariable: Yes, that's how I split $n$ into $n'$ and $n''$.