# Relationship between perfect squares and infinite series (zeta function)

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, perfect-powers

I noticed something when scribbling the zeta function -

$$\zeta(3) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3} = 1 + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{27} + \frac{1}{64} + \frac{1}{125} + \frac{1}{216} + \frac{1}{343} + \frac{1}{512} + \frac{1}{729} + \frac{1}{1000}\: +\: ...$$

and

$$\zeta(6)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^6} = 1 + \frac{1}{64} + \frac{1}{729} + \frac{1}{4096} + \frac{1}{15625} + \frac{1}{46656} + \frac{1}{117649}\: +\:  ...$$

Note that $64 = 2^6 = 4^3$, $729 = 3^6 = 9^3$, $4096=4^6=16^3$ ... because $$\zeta(6)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^6}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n^2)^3}$$

Substituting into $\zeta(3)$ produces

$$\zeta(3) = \zeta(6) + \Big(\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{27} + \frac{1}{125} + \frac{1}{216} + \frac{1}{343} + \frac{1}{512} + \frac{1}{1000}\: +\: ...\Bigr)$$

Every term that cancels is in the form of $4^3, 9^3, 16^3, 25^3, 36^3$. Thinking about the "perfect square" in reverse would generate the values of $2^6=64$, $3^6=729$, $4^6=4096$, $5^6=15625$ which correspond to the numbers above.

Is there any known summation formula for

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}$$

where n is not a perfect square such as 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64 ....

I scanned the internet and found [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2C%204%2C%209%2C%2016%2C%2025%2C%2036%2C%2049%20...) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).

[image]

Although, these don't seem to be of help. Is there a known summation formula for

$$\Big(\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{27} + \frac{1}{125} + \frac{1}{216} + \frac{1}{343} + \frac{1}{512} + \frac{1}{1000}\: +\: ...\Bigr)$$

which excludes all the perfect squares. Could I find this inside the OEIS?

If you doodle with $\zeta(3)$, you can also create

$$\zeta(3) = 1 + \frac{1}{8}\zeta(3) + \Bigl(\frac{1}{27} + \frac{1}{125} + \frac{1}{343} + \frac{1}{729} + \frac{1}{1331} + \frac{1}{2197}\: +\: ... \Bigr)$$

Although, this doesn't seem to help.

**Edit:** The Dirichlet eta function is defined as

$$\hspace{35mm}\eta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n-1} \over n^s}\hspace{45mm}\forall\hspace{2mm}\Re(s) > 0$$

You can derive this relationship by ([shown inside this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221994/riemann-zeta-function-manipulation?lq=1))

\begin{align*}
\zeta(s)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^s}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{(2n)^s}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}+2^{1-z}\,\zeta(s)\\
\end{align*}

the end result is

$$\hspace{43mm}(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s} \hspace{28mm}\forall\hspace{2mm}\Re(s) > 1$$

The answer below looks exactly like the [multiplication theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Hurwitz_zeta_function).

For

$$~\displaystyle\zeta(s)=\frac1{n^s}\sum_{k=1}^n\zeta\bigg(s,~\frac kn\bigg)~$$

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597867/the-multiplication-formula-for-the-hurwitz-generalized-riemann-zeta-function) is very similar, but has a slight variation. The answer for this post shows

We start with $\displaystyle \zeta(s,z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z+n)^{s}}$.

First, substitute in $mz$ for $z$:

$$\begin{align}
\zeta(s,mz) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(mz+n)^{s}} \\
&= \frac{1}{m^s}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z+\frac{n}{m})^{s}}.
\end{align}$$

Now write $n = n'm + n''$, where now $n'$ will range from $0$ to $\infty $ and $n''$ will range from $0$ to $m-1$. Putting this above gives
$$\begin{align}
&= \frac{1}{m^s}\sum_{\substack{n'\geq 0 \\ n'' \bmod m}} \frac{1}{(z+\frac{n''}{m} + n')^{s}} \\
&= \frac{1}{m^s} \sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} \sum_{n' \geq 0} \frac{1}{(z + \frac km + n')^s} \\
&= \frac{1}{m^s}\sum_{k =0}^{m-1}\zeta\left(s,z+\frac{k}{m}\right),
\end{align}$$

Set $z=0$ to get the desired form shown by the multiplication theorem.

Comment: I don't believe there is any nice formula: http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant

Comment: See the [Riemann $\zeta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), the [Hurwitz $\zeta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function), and the [Dirichlet $\eta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have rediscovered two obvious formulas: $~\displaystyle\zeta(x)=\frac1{n^x}\sum_{k=1}^n\zeta\bigg(x,~\frac kn\bigg),~$ and

$\eta(x)=\bigg(1-\dfrac2{2^x}\bigg)~\zeta(x),~$ where $\zeta(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the [Hurwitz $\zeta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function), and $\eta(\cdot)$ is the [Dirichlet $\eta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function)

function.

Comment: I don't see the Hurwitz zeta function. Can you please elaborate on how this is formed from the series above?

Comment: @Axion004: Basically, we split $\zeta(x)$ into groups of *n* consecutive terms. Within each such group, the first term's denominator is always of the form $an+1$, the second of the form $an+2$, etc., where *a* goes from zero to infinity. Then we regroup all terms of the form $(an+1)^{-x}$ into a single sub-series; the same for all terms of the form $(an+2)^{-x}$, etc. Then, within each such sub-series, we factor *n* outside the parentheses. Done!

Comment: Asked one more question due to inexperience.